# simprof error: "undef.zero is missing" despite defining and with a default value in the function

Tags: r, error-handling

I am trying to run a SIMPROF analysis on my data matrix.  However when trying to run the simprof() function I am getting the Error: argument :undef.zero" is missing, with no default.

The help firstly says that undef.zero is default to TRUE, while I have also tried specifying it as TRUE and specifying it as FALSE, with no success.  I have updated RSTUDIO as well as updating all packages (including clustsig)

My code is below, trying to specify as many parameters as possible but still it doesn't recognise the undef.zero. df is "benthic_coral_percent".

```
> benthicsimprof <- simprof(benthic_coral_percent, num.expected=1000, num.simulated=999, 
+       method.cluster="average", method.distance="braycurtis", 
+       method.transform="identity", alpha=0.05, 
+       sample.orientation="row", const=0, 
+       silent=TRUE, increment=100, 
+       undef.zero=TRUE, warn.braycurtis=TRUE)
Error: argument "undef.zero" is missing, with no default


> benthicsimprof <- simprof(benthic_coral_percent, num.expected=1000, num.simulated=999, 
+       method.cluster="average", method.distance="braycurtis", 
+       method.transform="identity", alpha=0.05, 
+       sample.orientation="row", const=0, 
+       silent=TRUE, increment=100, 
+       undef.zero=FALSE, warn.braycurtis=TRUE)
Error: argument "undef.zero" is missing, with no default
```

Any help would be great.

Many thanks.

Comment: Rstudio doesn't execute the code, it just passes it to R. From where I sit, a reproducible example would be most helpful.

Comment: Hi Roman, the data frame is just a basic species matrix, each sample is a row with each species a separate column. I can't work out how to add the sheet to the post otherwise I would!